# How to deactivate textbox validation until confirming the new row?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with two textboxes bound to a datatable.

The fields in the table are:
- ID   (AllowDBNull = false)
- Name (AllowDBNull = false)

I have a validation event handler for both textboxes:

```
Friend Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    Dim TextBox As TextBox = Sender

    If TextBox.Text = "" then
        e.Cancel = true
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when launching the application. If the first textbox is empty, it shows an error (which is normal) but I just can't get the focus out of it. For example, if TextBoxID receives the focus, I can't move to the second in case I want to fill the second first, which is very annoying.

Is there any way to deactivate this validation while typing and keep it at the end when the row will be inserted to the datatable ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, remove it from the event handler, and add it in your 'addToDatabase' routine

Comment: In that case, each time I want to insert or update a row, I have to remove the event handlers from all the controls, and add them back when updating the database. Isn't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till you are on a `Sub` there the abort of this `event` should be `Exit Sub`

If your `textbox` what should be not `Empty` is Named `TextBox1` ;

```
Friend Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
 if TextBox1.text.tostring.lenght = 0  then exit sub 
 end sub
```